# How to encrypt (Connection String) webconfig on deployment? For security reason

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I need to encrypt web config when deploy on live server for security reason

Comment: Exactly what sort of attack do you hope this encryption will prevent?

Comment: This won't achieve much. You'll stop people with access to the server from randomly seeing it. But ultimately since the code to decode it is on the server, it is a small step from being figured out. If you explain your architecture we could come up with a more secure solution.

Comment: If it's your connectionstring that you want to encrypt i suggest instead you create a user with limited permissions and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: @MattBall I mean if in case some one get access web config , then also he will not able to get access to db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two way to make your webconfig connection string secure.

1.There is IIS tool aspnet_regiis.exe IIS registration tool which will encrypt your connection string .
here is the command

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\
```

drop your web.config in c drive.
here is the doc -[Aspnet_regiis.exe documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

1. Add your connection string on Application_Start . that will also help.